# Jetty 9.2.x Websocket Server connection automatically closed after connect when using Firefox, not with Chrome

Tags: java, websocket, connection, jetty

I want to build an embedded Java WebSocket Server using Jetty. I am using Jetty 9.2.6.
My Client is a HTML javascript client.

With Google Chrome(39, WebSocket Version 13) I can establish a connection and send data bidirectional.
When i use Firefox (34, WebSocket Version 13), the connection closes directly after the connection is established. In my SocketListenerClass the onWebSocketConnect event is called, immediately the onWebSocketClose event is called.
I tried 3 versions for my Socket. Implementing the WebSocketListener, extends the WebSocketAdapter and using Annotations. Everywhere the same.

I get the close reason number 1005 (CLOSE_NO_STATUS) but sometimes 1001.

Here is my code:
Server:

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Server server = new Server(80);
    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    context.setContextPath("/");
    server.setHandler(context);
    context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new MyServlet()), "/*");
    try
      {
      server.start();
      server.join();
      }
    catch (Exception e)
      {
      e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
```

Servlet:

```
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet.WebSocketServlet;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet.WebSocketServletFactory;
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@WebServlet(name = "MyEcho WebSocket Servlet", urlPatterns = { "/egal" })
public class MyServlet extends WebSocketServlet
  {
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSocketServletFactory factory) {
        factory.register(MyEchoSocketWithListener.class);
    }
}
```

Socket:

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.Session;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.WebSocketListener;
public class MyEchoSocketWithListener implements WebSocketListener
  {
  private Session outbound;

  public void onWebSocketClose(int statusCode, String reason)
    {
    this.outbound = null;
    System.out.println("Session has been closed. Reason: +"+statusCode + " , "+reason);
    }

  public void onWebSocketConnect(Session session)
    {
    this.outbound = session;
    System.out.println("New Connection established...");
    }

  public void onWebSocketError(Throwable cause)
    {
    cause.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }

  public void onWebSocketText(String message)
    {
    if ((outbound != null) && (outbound.isOpen()))
      {
      System.out.printf("Echoing back message [%s]%n \n", message);
      outbound.getRemote().sendString("Server-Echo: " + message, null);
      }
    }
```

The JavaScript Client:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>page title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>WebSocket Test</h1>
<section id="content"></section>
<script>
var ws;
setTimeout(function (){initWebsocket();}, 3000);

function initWebsocket()
    {
    ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:80/egal");
    window.onbeforeunload = function ()
        {
        ws.onclose = function ()
            {
            }; // disable onclose handler first
        ws.close()
        };
    ws.onopen = function ()
        {
        document.write("WebSocket opened <br>");
        ws.send("Hello Server");
        document.write("Hello Message sent... <br>");
        };

    ws.onmessage = function (evt)
        {
        document.write("Message: " + evt.data + "<br>");
        };

    ws.onclose = function ()
        {
        document.write("<br>WebSocket closed<br>");
        };

    ws.onerror = function (err)
        {
        document.write("Error: " + err);
        };
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Servers output:
New Connection established... 
Session has been closed. Reason: +1005 , null

Why does it work on chrome and not on FF? They are using the same websocket version 13. I also tried Jetty 9.2.5, and a new Mozilla Nightly and an older Firefox Version. No difference here.

Comment: Your code works on Jetty 9.2.3 thru 9.2.6 (and even 9.3.0), on linux and OSX, using Firefox 34.0

Comment: Maybe this is an html/javascript issue.  Can you post that in your question too?

Comment: Thank yout for your answers. I added the clients javascript code above.
How you run the code? I tried running the server within the IDE IntelliJ and NetBeans. Also no difference here.
(I also tried different ports (80, 8080, 8081,...))
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your answers.
I solved the problem, it was caused by another stupid bug.

In my HTML client i was using the script tag inside the body. Also i was using document.write() in my websocket events. the document.write() method overrides the whole body content. So my javascript code is deleted at this moment.

Very stupid bug... sorry for that. :-)

I am asking myself, why it worked in Chrome anyway. :-)

Comment: Could you, please, add a description of what was causing this problems? "In my HTML client i was using the tag inside the body" - what tag, exactly?

Comment: I mean the script tag, i wrote it in "<" ">", so the stackoverflow editor doesn't display it...
The script block contains the websocket code and stores the handling. So by document.write() it gets overwritten and the session is deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new MyServlet()), "/*");
```

to

```
context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new MyServlet()), "/egal");
```

This is minor, and isn't the root cause of your issue.

Firefox is handling the close properly, its just closing before you get the response back from the server.

Close code 1005 just means the close occurred without a close code being passed.
If you change your `onbeforeunload()` implementation to use `ws.close(1000)` you'll see that your own javascript is closing the connection.  Comment out that line and you'll see the response message.

Went ahead and mocked up the 5 different ways you can create a websocket in embedded jetty at the following github project.

https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-websocket-echo-examples

Each demo loads an HTML + JavaScript to demonstrate connect / hello world / close

They all work with Chrome and Firefox